# How to Merge Two Authors Into One?

Tags: users

I have several posts in my WordPress site. Some posts belong to Author1 while others belong to Author2. Is there a way (plugin?) to merge the authors (For e.g. merge Author1 into Author2) and have all posts with one author name?

**Edit:** With "merge", the meaning is to be read as *"Remove one author, assign all **posts** to another"*.

Comment: plugin recommendations are off-topic

Comment: You cannot merge accounts, you can delete one author and reassign his posts to another author, or simply just reassign the posts

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is a good question and the answer is basic Wordpress 101 (core), contrary to the two comments above. No plugin necessary. You simply go to Users and delete the author (user) that you don't want to keep. Wordpress then asks you if you want to delete their content or attribute it to another user. Choose the author (user) you wish to keep and it will attribute all their posts across. Users/authors merged.

Comment: This is not merging, you are not combing two user accounts, you are simply deleting one account and reassigning posts ;-)

Comment: That's a pretty semantic point @PieterGoosen unless you want the merged user to have some special privileges or something (which wasn't outlined in the question). The end result suggested is simply the merging of their content (posts) into one author name.

Comment: Indeed, this is the proper answer for a standard merge, which is moving the posts from one author to another. If there are other things that Regi would like "merged", such as permissions, then Regi will need to specify. In the general case, deleting a user will have WordPress give you the option to merge existing content into a new user.